Terminology question regarding $L$ and "definable" real numbers
Wikipedia's page on "definable real number" says:

A real number $a$ is first-order definable in the language of set theory, without parameters, if there is a formula $\varphi$ in the language of set theory, with one free variable, such that $a$ is the unique real number such that $\varphi(a)$ holds. This notion cannot be expressed as a formula in the language of set theory.

My question: is this the same as saying that $a$ is in $\Bbb R \cap L$, or is there some subtle difference? Is one a superset of the other? Are they comparable?
The reason I'm thrown off about this is:

$L_\alpha$, in general, includes sets that are not just definable without parameters, but definable with parameters from the previous stage...
...but also, with a modified notion of quantification.
Although we can't express the definability of $a$ in ZFC, it seems there's some sense in which we can express $L$, since we can express axioms like $V = L$.
We would like to say there are only countably many definable real numbers, except ZFC can't prove what definability is. On the other hand, the cardinality of $\Bbb R \cap L$ depends on things like the existence of $0^\#$.

Is ZFC, perhaps augmented with some suitable large cardinal axiom, strong enough to say anything at all about this? How do these things fit together?

There is a significant difference. Yes.

If we're talking about $0^{#}$ existing... in any model of "$0^{#}$ exists", $0^{#}$ is a definable real that is not constructible.

@spaceisdarkgreen Yes, but that uses a significant (and unnecessary) consistency strength assumption.

The two collections in question are a priori extremely different. (To avoid metamathematical issues which obscure the subject in my opinion, I'm going to focus on the situation relative to a model in this answer.)

Letting $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ (for simplicity let's assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\omega$-model so that the things $\mathcal{M}$ thinks are reals actually are reals up to an obvious translation, but this won't substantively matter), we have two sets of reals to consider:

$\mathbb{R}\cap L^\mathcal{M}$, the set of reals which are elements of the constructible universe of $\mathcal{M}$.

$\mathbb{R}\cap D(\mathcal{M})$, the set of reals which are definable over $\mathcal{M}$ without parameters.


In general, neither of these need be a subset of the other. For the obvious non-inclusion, $\mathbb{R}\cap D(\mathcal{M})$ is countable while $\mathbb{R}\cap L^\mathcal{M}$ may not be (e.g. if $\mathcal{M}$ is transitive and $\omega_1^{L^\mathcal{M}}=\omega_1$); in the other direction, if $\mathcal{M}$ is countable we can form a generic extension $\mathcal{M}[G]$ such that $\{i: 2^{\aleph_{2i}}=\aleph_{2i+1}\}^{\mathcal{M}[G]}\}\not\in L^\mathcal{M[G]}=L^\mathcal{M}$, but that real is obviously in $D(\mathcal{M}[G])$.
It's a fun exercise to whip up (under reasonable hypotheses of course) a single countable transitive $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ witnessing both noninclusions simultaneously.

Thanks! Do you mean ${\omega_1}^{L^\mathcal{M}} = {\omega_1}^{\mathcal{M}}$ above?

I can see how there can be definable reals that aren't constructible - $0^#$ being a very good "typical" example - it's harder for me to see it going the other way. While I get there are all kinds of bizarre models which can have very strange notions of both definability and constructibility, is there any fairly intuitive example of a real number which is constructible but not definable? Is there anything as intuitive as $0^#$ but going the other way?

@MikeBattaglia Being an element of $L$ just implies that that set is definable with an ordinal parameter. For example, as my answer says, if $\omega_1^L=\omega_1$ then for cardinality reasons some $\alpha<\omega_1^L$ must be undefinable in $V$. Now consider a real $r\in L$ coding $\alpha$ (which exists since $\alpha<\omega_1^L$); any such $r$ must also be undefinable in $V$.

I can see that, but is there any way to build such a real without the assumption that $\omega_1^L = \omega_1$, which seems kind of strong? Or put another way: can we ever have a model where all constructible reals are definable, and how strong would that axiom be? It would seem incompatible with $V=L$ and the existence of $0^# at the same time.
